# Fixed position & centering not in center

Tags: html, css

I have been into learning more CSS and JS lately and I made this lame website :P. The problem I have got is with centering the "Commercial IP Detected" box on the last phase of my js script. Can you guys take a look into it, because I kind of gave up... Thanks :D

What I used to center it - inline:

```
style="top: 50%; left: 50%; display: block;"
```

the element is position:fixed as well

Like to to the website: http://baciu.ro/test/mortalkombatx-theme/

Link with picture of the problem: http://i60.tinypic.com/29eq71t.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: If you say "left at 50%" then LEFT SIDE of your block will be in the middle. *one* way is to use inline instead of block and auto margin for left and right.

Comment: When setting the element to center using `left: 50%; top: 50%;` you should add a negative `margin` half the width/height of the element. Like `margin-left: 200px;` to compensate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look on [Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) by Chris Coyier.

Otherwise, my favorite way for this kind of **fixed element** is

```
.element {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Or if there is no size defined:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Good Luck'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`style="transform: translate(-50%, -50%); top: 50%; left: 50%; display: block;"`

using above css, You don't need `position:fixed;`, and You don't need specific `width` and `height` in `px` for Your div.